# Why executor service takes more time than sequential operation in java 8?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

In the following program, I want to sort 4 different arrays in parallel, so used executorService to create FixedThreadPool with size 4(available processors count).
I assume that it would take less time compared to sequential operation but I see the sequential operation is faster. Any further optimization needed here?

Here is the code:

```
public class ThreadFoolOptimumSize {

private static int data1[] = new int[10000];
private static int data2[] = new int[20000];
private static int data3[] = new int[10000];
private static int data4[] = new int[30000];

public static void main(String ars[]) {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int processors_count = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    System.out.println(processors_count);
    Random random = new Random();
    data1 = random.ints(10000, 10, 10000).toArray();
    data2 = random.ints(20000, 10, 20000).toArray();
    data3 = random.ints(10000, 10, 10000).toArray();
    data4 = random.ints(30000, 10, 30000).toArray();

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(processors_count);
    executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Arrays.sort(data1);
            System.out.println("sorted data1:");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data1));
        }
    });

    executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Arrays.sort(data2);
            System.out.println("sorted data2:");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data2));
        }
    });

    executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Arrays.sort(data3);
            System.out.println("sorted data3:");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data3));
        }
    });

    executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Arrays.sort(data4);
            System.out.println("sorted data4:");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data4));
        }
    });

    executorService.shutdown();

    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Total:" + (endTime-startTime) + " ms");
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: You are creating `processors_count` threads, but a CPU core is needed to run the main thread.  And at least one core is needed to run the operating system.  Also, I would be interested in whether your sequential version uses a shutdown hook to compute the elapsed time.

Answer (score 2):

I repeated your test and confirm your observation: I simply think the setup of the Executor service has a cost, 
I did some further tests on a laptop with 8 cores and even increasing all the arrays by a factor of ten I still get the standard version to be faster.

Increasing another factor of ten  (so the sizes are of the order of millions) I finally get the Executor to become faster.

So it is clearly matter of how much data you have to process, in some cases it is not worth to use an Executor. (Of course I commented the printout of the sorted arrays).

On top of that add that using different arrays sizes makes the difference less eviedent: at the beginning you sort 4 arrays in parallel, after 1/3 of the time, you complete 2 of the sorts, data1 and data3, and continue to process the other two in parallel, data2 and data4, and the last third of the time you process on one array, data4. If you sort identical arrays the gain in speed will be more evident.

Finally let me add that the measured time fluctuates a lot, you have to repeat it a bit of times and average to get a stable number and do a proper test.
With sizes of few 100.000s the time fluctuates by as much as 50% on my laptop.